# Can't connect to a port but 80 in php

Tags: php, port, server-to-server

I have a webspace on a free hosting platform. The latter doesn't allow server-to-server connections to a port different from 80 in php scripts. I need to connect to another website on a port different from 80 using php Curl libraries, but obviusly it doesn't work, my host blocks the connection. Is there a method to bypass this limitation?

Comment: You will need to use a Internet proxy (CURLOPT_PROXY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's a firewall limitation and you can only ask your hosting company for specific permission.

But if you have control over another website, you can send request to it's 80 and route to port xx.